# A quite strange question about measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

this strange question just occurred to me, that say $E\subset[0,1]$ and $mE=1$, does it imply the closure $\overline E=[0,1]$? Or is there a closed proper set in $[0,1]$ that has measure $1$? In that case removing a limit point will satisfy my question. It seems easy but I just can not find a example....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if $A \subset [0,1]$ is closed of measure 1, then its complement is open of measure zero.  Clearly any nonempty open set has nonzero measure, so $A$ must have been $[0,1]$.

Comment: You are right...It is trivial.